Display an error after failed request with Vue3 and Vee Validate
I'm trying to display an error for a specific field after the failed request to the server with an error from the server, I'm finding this to be very difficult. I've reduced all the code I currently have to make this question as easy to understand here is my current NON working implementation:
<template>
  <Form @submit="onSubmit">
    <input
      v-model="leaguePassword"
      class="text-field"
      name="leaguePassword"
      type="password"
    />
    <ErrorMessage name="leaguePassword" />

    <button type="submit">Join League</button>
  </Form>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref } from "vue";
import { useField, useForm, Form, ErrorMessage } from "vee-validate";
import * as yup from "yup";
import axios from "axios";
import { useAuth0 } from "@auth0/auth0-vue";

const leaguePassword = ref("");
const { setFieldError } = useForm();
const { getAccessTokenSilently } = useAuth0();
useField("leaguePassword", yup.string().required());

const onSubmit = async () => {
  try {
    const token = await getAccessTokenSilently();
    await axios.post(
      import.meta.env.VITE_ROOT_API + "/users_leagues",
      {},
      {
        headers: { Authorization: "Bearer " + token },
      }
    );
    // Handle successful response if needed
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("hey")
    setFieldError("leaguePassword", "Incorrect password.");
  }
};
</script>

I thought that the setFieldError would add a message to the ErrorMessage component for the name 'leaguePassword' but that is not working. Basically the request is failing but it's not updating the dom with the error message.
How can I add an error message to the form AFTER a form request failure?

does console.log("hey") get executed?

You are not calling event.preventDefault() anywhere during your submission process, could you check if doing so could solve the issue? For instance wrtie @submit.prevent="onSubmit"
